# How to convert individual [x, y] co-ords into ranges of [xstart, xend,ystart, yend]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an application where I can draw tiles on an x-y grid, and paint a provided png. The goal is to then download the tiles as a .json file.

*Image of the problem*:

[image: Image of the problem]

Right now, I have it creating JSON as

`"woodenCrate":[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...]`

but I would like to turn it into:

`"woodenCrate":[[xstart, xend, ystart, yend],[xstart, xend, ystart, yend]...]`

So it would take all the individual points, and turn them into big chunks that I could draw. My current plan is to find the big rectangles inside the structure, and then repeat on the remaining pieces. Eventually I'll be left with a bunch of big rectangles, and a few single sized boxes outside it.

I have tiles in [x, y] integer positions.

**Example:**

`[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2][1,3]]`

should turn into:

`[[0,1,1,3]]`

A solution that converts into `[[startX, startY, width, height]]` is also fine.

How should I approach this problem? I'm using Javascript.

Comment: you can't convert a point to a rectangle, you need minimum 2 points to construct a rectangle so [x1,y1], [x2,y2] => [xs,xe,ys,ye] but not from [x,y]

Comment: I'll update my question to better explain, there seems to be some miscommunication.

Comment: Have you done [some research](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-hmd-rev2&ei=0YWNXZe9FI7XkwWJtaeQCA&q=merge+mesh+algorithms) ?

Comment: I have, but all of the answers I've come across have been unhelpful. I specifically say "How should I approach" I'm not asking for an answer, I'm asking to be put in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I made code that finds the biggest possible rectangle in the structure.

Then I pull out that rectangle, and I repeat on the leftover structure.

Eventually I get a few 1x1 pieces, but overall I have fewer entries in my JSON file for larger structures that I made.

If you want to read this code look at the "rangeOptimizer.js" file on my "tile-placer-v2" repository. My github username is the same as my stackoverflow one.

I sincerely doubt that it is the most optimal solution, but as far as I can see the method answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vague suspicion that just encoding all single rows (or columns) of the rectangles will also work, if the rectangle sizes aren't super huge.

Comment: This isn't an answer, I feel it should be a comment. Also, doing rows and columns does not do a good job of finding the best ranges to use. My approach exhausts all possible rectangles and pulls out the biggest one each time.

Comment: I have no idea what properties you want in a solution - the fastest algorithm, to produce as small output as possible or to find the biggest rectangle. Hence a suggestion that is reasonable for non-gigantic rectangles.

Comment: A "vague suspicion" is not an answer to the problem I am facing. If I were to encode all rows I would have an array of arrays that are size 3 (startx, starty, width). Which does match the format I need. I specifically say what properties I need. startX, startY, endX (or width), endY (or height).